# Can i clear the serial port every time after reading the data from it?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

i need to clear the data on serial port when i have read the data from it before i read the data again? i m using c/c++ on windows xp

how can i do so  ?

thanx in advance.

Comment: There is no such language as C/C++, and neither C nor C++ has support for serial ports. This must be provided by your operating system - which one are you using?

Comment: Besides, you don't need to "clear data" after reading it. Serial ports are almost always implemented with FIFO buffers. Reading a byte removes it from that buffer.

Comment: The problem I see with this is that data arrives at a serial port asynchronously. All you know is that the data you just read already arrived. In the very next moment, new data could have arrived - or not. When you flush the port, you don't even know whether you throw away data, nor how much or which. I have no experience with serial communication protocols, so maybe I'm missing something obvious, but it does seem strange to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ standard has interfaces for writing to files, to the screen and to a log.  It also has interfaces for reading from files and reading from "standard input."  There is no standard way to interact with serial ports, network connections, etc.

Luckily your operating system or platform will have an interface for this.  But (1) what you have to do to read from a serial connection, and (2) what you need to do between consecutive reads, and (3) how to do it are all platform dependent.

---

Looking at [some Microsoft Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810467.aspx), you don't have to "clear the port" at all.  But when a flag is set to signal something -- for instance that an error occurred -- then you need to reset the flag before continuing.  Of course you reset the flag **after** handling whatever the flag was meant to signal.

Answer (score 3):

Purging the receive buffer is almost always wrong.  Serial port communications are asynchronous by nature, you'll risk deleting good data.  Only if you use a master-slave protocol (the device only ever transmits when queried by the host) would allow purging.  But then, if the receive buffer actually has data to purge then you're ignoring a protocol violation, something you *never* want to just ignore.

Reliable serial port communication requires a protocol.  A checksum to verify message integrity and ACK/NAK handshaking to recover from data corruption.  Check out the RATP protocol, described in RFC 916.  Widely ignored btw but I've used it in the past.  Its only weakness is buffered connection attempts.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution is not the best, but it is suitable for many cases:

Read a large number of bytes from the serial port rendering it empty. For example:

ReadFile(Port,TMP,4096,&ioread,NULL);

tmp[ ]: is the variable that will hold the data that you don't want (flush data)
ioread: Number of bytes read

So the above will read 4096 bytes from the serial port. You can increase the number to make sure you end up with a clean port after the statement.

P.S. I had used this with Visual Studio 2010, C++, Windows 7 - 64 bit